# Does R have any package for parsing out the parts of a URL?

Tags: r, parsing, url

I have a list of urls that I would like to parse and normalize.

I'd like to be able to split each address into parts so that I can identify "www.google.com/test/index.asp" and "google.com/somethingelse" as being from the same website.

Comment: What's your intended output?

Comment: The idea case would be something that splits things like [tldextract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract), but if that is not readily availible, I would like to get back the string up until the end of the top level domain (e.g. .com or .edu). Preferably it would also strip away http:// and www. and other prefixes like that.

Comment: Could you give us an example output of what you'd expect with your example rather than giving a url for us to parse through and read.

Comment: There now appears to be a [tldextract package](https://github.com/jayjacobs/tldextract) available for R. Here is [a blogpost describing](http://www.r-bloggers.com/parsing-domain-names-in-r-with-tldextract/) it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since [`parse_url()`](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/R/url.r) uses regular expressions anyway, we may as well reinvent the wheel and create a single regular expression replacement in order to build a sweet and fancy `gsub` call.

Let's see. A URL consists of a protocol, a "netloc" which may include username, password, hostname and port components, and a remainder which we happily strip away. Let's assume first there's no username nor password nor port.

- `^(?:(?:[[:alpha:]+.-]+)://)?` will match the protocol header (copied from `parse_url()`), we are stripping this away if we find it
- Also, a potential `www.` prefix is stripped away, but not captured: `(?:www\\.)?`
- Anything up to the subsequent slash will be our fully qualified host name, which we capture: `([^/]+)`
- The rest we ignore: `.*$`

Now we plug together the regexes above, and the extraction of the hostname becomes:

```
PROTOCOL_REGEX <- "^(?:(?:[[:alpha:]+.-]+)://)?"
PREFIX_REGEX <- "(?:www\\.)?"
HOSTNAME_REGEX <- "([^/]+)"
REST_REGEX <- ".*$"
URL_REGEX <- paste0(PROTOCOL_REGEX, PREFIX_REGEX, HOSTNAME_REGEX, REST_REGEX)
domain.name <- function(urls) gsub(URL_REGEX, "\\1", urls)
```

Change host name regex to include (but not capture) the port:

```
HOSTNAME_REGEX <- "([^:/]+)(?::[0-9]+)?"
```

And so forth and so on, until we finally arrive at an [RFC-compliant regular expression for parsing URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/946850). However, for home use, the above should suffice:

```
> domain.name(c("test.server.com/test", "www.google.com/test/index.asp",
                "http://test.com/?ex"))
[1] "test.server.com" "google.com"      "test.com"
```

Comment: The advantage of using code from a package is that it comes with unit tests, and you can file bug reports and someone else might fix the bug.

Comment: @hadley: Thanks for commenting on that. I haven't found unit tests for `parse_url`, though. If they were available, `parse_url` could be rewritten so that a single regular expression is used to capture all parts of an URL. -- Is it by design that the protocol prefix is mandatory for `parse_url`?

Comment: Yeah, I should have said the advantage of a package is that it _could_ come with unit tests. Patches welcome ;)   I'd argue that the current answer is correct when the scheme is omitted - if you used that url in a web page, it would not take you to google.com.

Comment: I also don't see what the advantage of a single extremely complicated regexp is.

Comment: @hadley: The regexp could be decomposed the way I did in my answer, to make it more readable in the source code. Performance and vectorization would be an immediate advantage: If all components are captured, replacing in `gsub` by `"\\1\n\\2\n\\3\n..."` and splitting all strings afterwards should be faster than chewing the URL bit by bit.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the function of the R package httr

```
 parse_url(url) 
 >parse_url("http://google.com/")
```

You can get more details here:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf

Comment: Could you please provide example output for one of the URLs the OP has provided?

Comment: This is getting a ton of upvotes so I must me missing something.  How can this help determine what urls belong together?

Comment: `parse_url("www.google.com/test/index.asp")$path` gives a result of
`"www.google.com/test/index.asp"`
which is not very helpful.

Comment: @TylerRinker: I, too, have assumed that this function *must* split the URL into its building blocks, without really reading the docs. I have added the missing parts in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17286485/946850).

Comment: @TylerRinker: Actually, `parse_url` *does* split the URL into its building blocks. It's just that the protocol prefix is mandatory, and the split will be incorrect if the protocol prefix is missing. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's also the `urltools` package, now, which is *infinitely* faster:

```
urltools::url_parse(c("www.google.com/test/index.asp", 
                      "google.com/somethingelse"))

##                  scheme         domain port           path parameter fragment
## 1        www.google.com      test/index.asp                   
## 2            google.com       somethingelse
```

Comment: This is really much better than the httr::url_parse, not only for the blazing speed but also for the vectorisation (no need to use *apply)

Answer (score 4):

I'd forgo a package and use regex for this.

**EDIT** reformulated after the robot attack from Dason...

```
x <- c("talkstats.com", "www.google.com/test/index.asp", 
    "google.com/somethingelse", "www.stackoverflow.com",
    "http://www.bing.com/search?q=google.com&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=google.com&sc=8-1??0&sp=-1&sk=")

parser <- function(x) gsub("www\\.", "", sapply(strsplit(gsub("http://", "", x), "/"), "[[", 1))
parser(x)

lst <- lapply(unique(parser(x)), function(var) x[parser(x) %in% var])
names(lst) <- unique(parser(x))
lst

## $talkstats.com
## [1] "talkstats.com"
## 
## $google.com
## [1] "www.google.com/test/index.asp" "google.com/somethingelse"     
## 
## $stackoverflow.com
## [1] "www.stackoverflow.com"
## 
## $bing.com
## [1] "http://www.bing.com/search?q=google.com&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=google.com&sc=8-1??0&sp=-1&sk="
```

This may need to be extended depending on the structure of the data.

Comment: Somebody actually has built an [RFC-compliant regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/946850) for URLs. This is not for the faint of heart, and a dedicated URL parser should be preferred here...

Comment: `x <- "http://www.bing.com/search?q=google.com&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=google.com&sc=8-10&sp=-1&sk="` You just identified bing as google.

Comment: @Dason who searches for google with bing? :) I'll update but I think the OP doesn't want to supply a pattern explicitly.

Comment: People trying to destroy raptor's hopes and dreams.

Comment: @TylerRinker: R can handle [PCREs](http://www.pcre.org/) for sure (set `perl=T`), and you can extract the relevant parts by substituting some of the `(?:` in the supplied regular expression by `(` and, say,  `gsub`bing with `"\\1"` to get the value of the first placeholder.

Comment: `x <- http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/45040-www.google.com?p=130154#post130154` No bing search there :p

Comment: Let's be honest, "google.com" is one of the most common searches on bing.

Comment: @krlmlr that sounds cool but is way above my pay grade (i.e., my ability level).  Would you mind showing as an answer?

Comment: Your solution doesn't handle https properly.

Comment: @TylerRinker: I still consider using custom regular expressions to parse URLs less than optimal, especially (as just seen) if there is a library available to do just that. That's why I'm not posting an answer, but let me elaborate on what I wrote earlier. The regular expression I have pointed to is one that R can interpret by supplying `perl=T` to `grep`, `gsub` and friends. Note the strangely looking `(?:` construct -- this is a [non-capturing subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php). Also remember that plain parentheses allow *capturing* the matched text...

Comment: @TylerRinker: ...and reusing it with the `\#` syntax where `#` is a digit. Reusing works in both the pattern and the replacement text (in `gsub`). Just try: `gsub("^.* have ([0-9]+) .*$", "\\1", "I have 17 apples")`

Answer (score 3):

Building upon R_Newbie's answer, here's a function that will extract the server name from a (vector of) URLs, stripping away a `www.` prefix if it exists, and gracefully ignoring a missing protocol prefix.

```
domain.name <- function(urls) {
    require(httr)
    require(plyr)
    paths <- laply(urls, function(u) with(parse_url(u),
                                          paste0(hostname, "/", path)))
    gsub("^/?(?:www\\.)?([^/]+).*$", "\\1", paths)
}
```

The `parse_url` function is used to extract the `path` argument, which is further processed by `gsub`. The `/?` and `(?:www\\.)?` parts of the regular expression will match an optional leading slash followed by an optional `www.`, and the `[^/]+` matches everything after that but before the first slash -- this is captured and effectively used in the replace text of the `gsub` call.

```
> domain.name(c("test.server.com/test", "www.google.com/test/index.asp",
                "http://test.com/?ex"))
[1] "test.server.com" "google.com"      "test.com"
```

Comment: There's a ton of extra overhead in this in that `parse_url` generates a larger list of information than what is needed and the output still needs to be regexed.  I really think that the perl approach you alluded to may be useful to see.

Answer (score 2):

If you like tldextract one option would be to use the version on appengine

```
require(RJSONIO)
test <- c("test.server.com/test", "www.google.com/test/index.asp", "http://test.com/?ex")
lapply(paste0("http://tldextract.appspot.com/api/extract?url=", test), fromJSON)
[[1]]
   domain subdomain       tld 
 "server"    "test"     "com" 

[[2]]
   domain subdomain       tld 
 "google"     "www"     "com" 

[[3]]
   domain subdomain       tld 
   "test"        ""     "com"
```

Comment: That's clever, I hadn't seen that tool before.